# Find items with maximum matching attributes

Tags: mysql, sql, entity-attribute-value

Here is my table structure - table name "propAssign"

```
(indexed)        (composite index for attributeName and attributeValue)
 productId     attributeName     attributeValue 
    1              Height             3
    1              Weight             1
    1              Class              X1
    1              Category           C1
    2              Height             2
    2              Weight             2 
    2              Class              X2
    2              Category           C1
    3              Height             3
    3              Weight             1
    3              Class              X1
    3              Category           C1
    4              Height             4
    4              Weight             5
    4              Class              X2
    4              Category           C3
```

What I want to do is, get list of productId, sorted by maximum matching attributes-value pair. In real table, I am using numeric ID of attribute name and value, I've used text here for easy representation.

So if I want to find matching products of productId=1, I want it to look for product which has maximum match (like Height=3, Weight=1, Class=X1 and Category=C1). There may not be any with 100% match (all 4 match) but if there are, they should come first, next comes productId which has any 3 attributes matching, then any 2, etc.

I could add more indexes if required, better if I don't have to since there are millions rows. It's MariaDB v10 to be exact.

Desired result - If I try to find matching product for productId=1, it should return following, in same order.

```
productId
-----------
3
2
```

Reason - 3 has all attributes matching with 1, 2 has some matches and 4 has no match.

Comment: Number of attributes could be large amount, and unknown. Attributes for the selected product have to fetched by querying same table by productId

Comment: EAV schema sucks.  You have made it suck even worse by normalizing the attribute name and value !  You'll notice that @Vishnu did not even get into that level of complexity.

Comment: Why do people forget that tables have names?  It would also be sensible to show the result you expect from the sample data.

Comment: @RickJames I didn't know this schema had a name. I am more of a programmer and came up with this structure after analyzing data, didn't think about how to retrieve results at that time.

Comment: @RickJames Is there any better way to store an utilize this data? I can try and reorganize. It's not live system at the moment.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'll be careful next time :)

Comment: You could try to be careful this time and specify the table name.

Comment: @Mihir Well, I would have thought it fairly obvious that a normalised structure might look like  `productId,Height,Weight,Class,etc`

Comment: @Strawberry If you are referring to create columns for each property, that's not possible because they are in thousands.

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation to retrieve the productId's with the highest number of matches first.

```
select productId, 
    count(case when attributeName = 'Height' and attributeValue='3' then 1 end)
    + count(case when attributeName = 'Weight' and attributeValue='1' then 1 end)
    + count(case when attributeName = 'Category' and attributeValue='C1' then 1 end) as rank
from mytable
group by productId
order by rank desc
```

The query above returns all rows even with 0 matches. If you only want to return rows with 1 or more matches, then use the query below, which should be able to take advantage of your composite index:

```
select productId, count(*) as rank
from mytable
where (attributeName = 'Height' and attributeValue = '3')
or (attributeName = 'Weight' and attributeValue = '1')
or (attributeName = 'Category' and attributeValue = 'C1')
group by productId
order by rank desc
```

Comment: Even though I want dynamic name/values retrieval for given productId, I tried this query to test results. I am not sure if it's utilizing the composite index I've configured, since it's eating up a lot of server. I haven't been able to see the result since my table has millions of rows. Is it possible to specify which index to use in this particular "case" query? I've never used this type of queries before.

Comment: This query returns all rows from the table even with 0 matches but you can speed it up by only returning rows with 1 or more matches